# How to make number wrap back to maximum value

Tags: java, math

Sorry if the title is vague, and if this doesn't belong here (since it's more of a maths question) but I have a problem.

Here I have an algorithm, that adds a number to another number (e.g current += step) and if that number is greater than the max value, the remainder of the step is added to the minimum:

```
int current = 89;
int step = 4;
final int max = 90;
final int min = 29;

current += step;
if(current > max) current %= max;
System.out.println(current + min); // this will give 32
```

My question is, how  would I do this backwards, so that if the number is less than the minimum, the remainder is taken away from the maximum. I have tried some different things but none of them seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some more examples of input vs expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this snippet of code:

```
int current = 30;
int step = 4;
current -= step;
if (current < this.min) {
    current = this.min - current;
}
System.out.println(this.max - current); // this will give 87
```